# creating action with paypal ipn

Tags: function, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is my first time attempting to use paypal ipn.  I am an amateur coder for sure.  I have developed a user/subscriber site and I am wanting to finalize the paypal subscriber payments.

I have a number of questions but I know I should narrow it down to 1.

I understand ipn as sending a message to a page on my site.  (I may be wrong).  I am going to assume that would be the IPN handler URL. (?)

Does the IPN actually hit the page and create an action?

I would like that message (or loading of the page) to call a function which inserts in my database.

Here is my Listener...ipnverify.php

```
<?php require(Config::get('URL').'/paypalipn/PaypalIPN.php');
 use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PayPalIPN();
$ipn->useSandbox();$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();$name = $_POST['custom'];

if ($name==1) {



 function updatePaypalTest()
{


    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO paypal_test (name) VALUES('1')";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();


}

 updatePaypalTest();

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
?>
```

And then the other file from github...PaypalIPN.php

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
private $use_sandbox = true;
private $use_local_certs = false;
/*
 * PayPal IPN postback endpoints
 */
const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
/*
 * Possible responses from PayPal after the request is issued.
 */
const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
const INVALID = 'INVALID';
/**
 * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
 * should not be enabled in production).
 * @return void
 */
public function useSandbox()
{
    $this->use_sandbox = true;
}
/**
 * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
 * @return string
 */
public function getPaypalUri()
{
    if ($this->use_sandbox) {
        return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
    } else {
        return self::VERIFY_URI;
    }
}
/**
 * Verification Function
 * Sends the incoming post data back to paypal using the cURL library.
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function verifyIPN()
{
    if ( ! count($_POST)) {
        throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
    }
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = [];
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2) {
            // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
            if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                    $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                }
            }
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }
    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // Post the data back to paypal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
    $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
    if ($this->use_local_certs) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Connection: Close']);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $http_code = $info['http_code'];
    if ($http_code != 200) {
        throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
    }
    if ( ! ($res)) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errstr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    // Check if paypal verfifes the IPN data, and if so, return true.
    if ($res == self::VALID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Please help me understand what I am missing.  Is there a way that I can call my function from the ipn message?

Comment: Have you enabled and set up IPN on your PayPal Account yet?

Comment: yes.  I actually chose to go a different direction.  using authorize.net's api.  coupled with paymentdepot fees are much less.